# Asserting value from certain row on table

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to assert a value from a certain row on a table. The row I am trying to assert the value of will always have the same description, but where the row is on the table might change according to what document gets loaded to create the table from.

My Question is, How am I able to assert the value in the row where the description is `Parts Inventory` Here is the HTML to the row on the table I am trying to assert
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should work:

```js
cy.contains('01 - Parts inventory').parent().next().children()
.should('have.text','2899869.56')
```

Comment: I am able to find the text, but when trying to assert the value it times out.

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Was the difference between the first and second answer just changing the "have.value" to "have.text" ?

Comment: Yes, that was the difference. Obv. it's text not a value